# Mule esb: Validate array items in .raml file

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, raml

I have the following json schema definition in my .raml file

```
- request: |
   {
 "type": "object",
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
 "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
 "required": true,
 "properties": {
     "personProperty": {
         "type": "array",
         "items": {                 
                 "$ref": "property"                 
         }
     }
 }
   }
- property: |
   {   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
       "type": "object",
       "description": "A single person property",
       "properties": {
           "fieldId":  { "type": "integer", "required": true},
           "systemId": { "type": "integer", "required": false},
           "value":    { "type": "string" , "required": true },
           "created":  { "type": "string" , "required": false }
        }
   }
```

I need mule ESB to reject the input when one of the required fields inside the array is missing.

For example this should be rejected with 400- BAD REQUEST:

```
 {
"personProperty": [
    {
        "fieldId": "1",
        "systemId": 1,
        "created": "2015-02-23 21:19:00.907"
    }
]
}
```

If the schema is not inside an array, the validation works properly.
But when inside the array, it is not validating any single item having the required attribute.

Do I need a special configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the schema when you have it inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for a while I was able to make it work using this:

```
 - request: |
{
"type": "object",
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
"id": "http://jsonschema.net",
"definitions": {
    "person-property": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "fieldId": {
                "type": "integer",
                "required": true
            },
            "systemId": {
                "type": "integer",
                "required": false
            },
            "value": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true
            },
            "created": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false
            }
        }
    }
},
"properties": {
    "personProperty": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/person-property"
        }
    }
}
}
```

I used an inner definition and then called it using "$ref": "#/definitions/person-property"

Answer (score 0):

You have not answered my question so I can only assume that you had wrongly included the inner object definition. Seeing your own answer and the reference to struggling, I'd like to propose an answer too.

Here is a standalone and reference free representation of your schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "properties": {
        "personProperty": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "fieldId": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "systemId": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "created": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```